# JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter start phase finishing observation

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In our system we have `JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` with `auto-startup` property `false` value by default.

In integration tests we have to add 2-3 sec. delay before call `adapter.start()` in a test code and having ability for sending message in the correct way (otherwise it's simply lost).

How it's possible to check if JMS adapter startup phase was finished and adapter is ready for correct message consuming?

Comment: The question isn't clear. The `adapter.start()` is blocking code. You can't go further until it is dome its work. How about to share that test-case to play from our side? Thanks

Comment: @ArtemBilan my coworker has already asked the question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667463/message-driven-channel-adapter-drops-first-message-after-app-context-startup-unl and got an answer on a basis of `isRegisteredWithDestination`. Anyway we have to wait somehow.

Comment: OK. Not sure how that helps though... Why just don't share test-case and that's all? I can't dig SO for similar questions all the day.

Comment: Well, if Gary's answer doesn't feet your requirements, I think you don't have choice unless spin your JMS Broker (ActiveMQ ?) somehow to check if listener has subscribed, since JMS Channel Adapter is fully based on the JMS spec

Comment: @ArtemBilan I suppose the coworker will adopt Gary's code somehow to our needs. Thanks.